# Clickable element with ThreeJS PerspectiveCamera

Tags: three.js

I’ve created a panoramic image with PerspectiveCamera and all went well. I’ve also managed to add controls.
Now I want to place a clickable element (link/button/whatever) in the scene but I have no clue how to add and position the clickable element…every tip/suggestion is highly appreciated! Here is my code sofar:

```
function init() {

    const container = document.getElementById( 'three-image' );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
    // invert the geometry on the x-axis so that all of the faces point inward
    geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );

    //let imageLocation = <?php echo $block->getPanoramaImages();?>;
    let imageLocation = '/three/luifel.jpg';
    //alert(imageLocation)

    const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(imageLocation);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    container.style.touchAction = 'none';
    container.addEventListener( 'pointerdown', onPointerDown );

    document.addEventListener( 'wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a Raycaster. [Here it is in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) and you can also see it [in action in the exaples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=raycas#webgl_interactive_cubes). That example is activating each square on 'mousemove', so you can add a 'click' event listener with the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to attach an html element to a 3d element, you can project a 3d position to 2d and use that.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(100,0,0); // some point
vector.project(camera);


var widthHalf =  window.innerWidth / 2;
var heightHalf = window.innerHeight / 2;

vector.x = vector.x * widthHalf + widthHalf;
vector.y = -(vector.y * heightHalf) + heightHalf;
vector.z = 0;
```

If you want to attach to an object, use the objects position in world space:

```
vector.setFromMatrixPosition(obj.matrixWorld);
vector.project(camera);
```

...etc

EDIT:
I've created an example here:
https://codepen.io/flatworldstudio/pen/LYbgvgY

Comment: Hi flatworldstudio,
The issue is that I would like the html-element added to a 3d element (in my case the perspective camera).
I understand what you say but where is the html (object) for
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(100,0,0);

Say I have a <div id="tip"></div> and would like to add it to the scene...how do I add it?? (excuse me for being a beginner... :) )

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to answer but thought it might help others,

[Here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-text) is an article to add HtmlElement in various way: